# Laravel 8.55 php artisan migrate behavior after php artisan schema:dump --prune

Tags: php, migration, laravel-8

I ran php artisan schema:dump --prune in my development environment.

The schema folder appeared and the migrations folder was cleared as expected.

I've created 2 new migrations to create 2 new tables BUT when I run php artisan migrate, it attempts to run the old migrations.

Since trying, I've cleared the migrations table entries, cleared the cache/config/etc.

I also ran 'composer dump-autoload' but it has not changed the outcome.

Every time I run a php artisan migrate:fresh --seed, it errors out on a migration file that, technically, no longer exists.

I've been searching but have found nothing that covers this scenario.

The output of the php artisan migrate:fresh --seed is as follows:

```
> php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Loading stored database schema: C:\Users\philc\Dropbox\heroku_git\mCentric\datab
ase\schema/mysql-schema.dump
Loaded stored database schema. (3,774.21ms)
Migrating: 2016_03_01_193027_create_sent_emails_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sent_emails' a
lready exists (SQL: create table `sent_emails` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_
increment primary key, `hash` char(32) not null, `headers` text null, `sender` v
archar(255) null, `recipient` varchar(255) null, `subject` varchar(255) null, `c
ontent` text null, `opens` int null, `clicks` int null, `created_at` timestamp n
ull, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4
_unicode_ci')

  at C:\Users\philc\Dropbox\heroku_git\mCentric\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Ill
uminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll
 format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make th
is exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa
se's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

  1   C:\Users\philc\Dropbox\heroku_git\mCentric\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Il
luminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 T
able 'sent_emails' already exists")

  2   C:\Users\philc\Dropbox\heroku_git\mCentric\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Il
luminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

The referenced sent_email table is in the DB, of course, but my migrations folder only has 2 migrations files for tables that are not included in the schema.php file.

I saw (somewhere, but I forget where) that because those migration files might exist in other git branches, that it could be the cause of the error.

Does anyone know if that's at all possible/true ?

Comment: Hello, can you please share output from the commands you have tried in laravel

Comment: Added output above.